Dynamic values in a Vega Dropdown
I'm trying to build a custom dropdown in Vega - Writing plain JSON code in Kibana via Custom Visualization and not using any programming for Vega such as VegaJS
The default Vega dropdown supports a static list using an options key.
Ref: https://vega.github.io/vega/docs/signals/#:~:text=Description-,options,-Array
{
    "name": "Choose", "value": "A",
    "bind": {"input": "select", "options": ["A", "B", "C"]}
}

Can we use customize this list to set this value based on datasource ? Ex: datum.<some_variable>
PS: There was a discussion happened for the same in the Google group https://groups.google.com/g/vega-js/c/U58eEOv618U - The last comment in that chat and there's no update to it
Tried datum.<some_variable> and did not worked

Not currently possible to my knowledge. I would raise an issue on GitHub.
